# AVAssetExportSession exportSessionWithAsset:presetName: failing on iPad Pro Simulator

Tags: ios, ipad, audio

On the Xcode 7.1.1 **iPad Pro simulator**, the following AVAssetExportSession method returns nil, given a valid AVAsset:

```
AVAssetExportSession *exportSession = [AVAssetExportSession exportSessionWithAsset:avAsset presetName:AVAssetExportPresetAppleM4A];
```

This method **always** succeeds for me on other iOS 8 and 9 devices and simulators.

I don't have an actual iPad Pro, so I'm not sure whether this is specific to the iPad Pro simulator.

Does anyone have any info on this? (I use AVAssetExportSession to trim the ends of audio files.)

Also, is there a way to query for the error associated with a failure for this method (since it doesn't return an error code)?

Here is a link to my sample Xcode project, stored on Dropbox. If anyone has an **actual iPad Pro** device, could you try running this? In the onExportAudio: method, could you see whether exportSession gets set to nil? (There's also an audio trimming method that gets called if exportSession is valid...I would be curious if the trimming code successfully trims the 4 second source audio file into a 2 second destination audio file.) ... https://www.dropbox.com/s/zy2qpx94h2pltpi/AudioExportTest_711.zip?dl=0

Thank you!

-Allan

Comment: Happening here too. :(

Answer (score 2):

I tried reproducing this issue on a real iPad Pro today, and the issue did not occur.

It appears to be Simulator-specific.

-Allan

Comment: Ouch. I'm getting it too on iPhone simulator